# Application Works Fine In Debugging But On Run

Tags: android, android-asynctask, root

I'm trying to execute a command within an application. I'm doing it using a library called [RootTools](https://code.google.com/p/roottools/). The command I'm using is:

```
RootTools.getShell(true).add(new CommandCapture(0, 'dd if=boot.img of=/dev/block/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.0/by-name/boot')).waitForFinish();
```

The application works fine when I enabled Eclipse debugging mode. However that line did not work when it runs normal mode.

This class uses AsyncTask which allows me to execute another command once the main task is completed in a method called [onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29).

I noticed that under any mode the method onPostExecute works perfectly. But not the main method, [doInBackground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29).

I tried placing a Thread.sleep to add some delay but that didn't help either.

Comment: when did not work, did it generate error?

Comment: There is no error occurred. In order to see if there's changes I will need to reboot the device.

When I reboot it with debug enabled I see that there is changes. But not when it's running under normal mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning RootTools debugging on when running that command and verify that the command is being executed by examining the debug output in logcat.

RootTools.debugMode = true;

Comment: I didn't try that. But from debugging I saw that it executed successfully. However the result of the execution shows there's an exception. The message of the exception is the expected result of the executed command. I'm not sure why does it being treated as an exception.

Comment: Can you show me? I might be able to shed some light on what is happening. Pastebin maybe?

(BTW, I noticed in your code there is a syntax error, you did not include the closing quote...also, I think you should use double quotes instead of single?)

Comment: Sure I will do so soon. At work currently. The syntax error was a mistake and didn't apply to the code. I re-wrote it on the post instead of copy and paste it.

Comment: Hi Stericson. By enabling the debug mode I found this error from the log replace boot.img? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: error: invalid response [e]. Full content of the log can be seen here - https://gist.github.com/3730257.

Comment: Funny thing. I upgraded to RootTools 2.4 and it works flawlessly. Thanks for your help and also for releasing RootTools 2.4 :D

Comment: Awesome, not sure what I fixed that solved the problem but I am glad it did :D

Answer (score 0):

try to use the Async task in a function to get rid of this problem as follows

```
private void anyfunction()
   {
     new AsyncTask().execute();
    }
```

Comment: I did that in another class to initiate the task.

    new FlashTask().execute().get();

Comment: Try to use the Asysn task class in the same class in which you are calling this,surely you will get rid of this problem.Some it happens that if you are using the Async task in another class and calling it from another then it will create some issues.try to use in the same class.

Comment: To make sure I get it right. I should implement the task class as a private class?

Comment: It's the same.  

    new FlashTask().execute().get(). 

Only that I have moved FlashTask to a private inner class of the calling class.